# Should I use "run program" or "open program"?

Tags: word-choice

For computer programs, should I use "run program" or "open program"? Example:

- "I want to run Chrome."
- "I want to open Chrome."

Which of these words is the most used for this case?

Comment: You can also use “Bring up a Chrome window”  “Start Chrome”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this really depends on the context. "Run" implies an active process that persists over time, whereas "open" represents a one-time event.

> I'm running Chrome in the background.

> I opened Chrome to access Google.

Comment: I think it depends where it is nstalled and where it executes. If it's on a remote server, particularly if it's a web applixation or web page, I would ssy you "open" it. If it's installed locally on your device I would say that you "run" it. There are many shades of meaning and complex combinations bu thst's a start.

Answer (score 1):

The most common word here is *launch*. I want to *launch Chrome*.

Source: years of technical writing in software environments.

Answer (score -1):

I tried [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=launch%20Chrome%2Copen%20Chrome%2Cstart%20Chrome%2Crun%20Chrome&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) to compare the popularity of various words.

[image: Ngram]